# PHP heredoc parse error

Tags: string, php, heredoc

This produces output page OK

```
$mystring = "<<<EOT";
```

Replacing it with the following produces

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file.php on line 737

```
$mystring = <<<EOT
   This is some PHP text.
   It is completely free
   I can use "double quotes"
   and 'single quotes',
   plus $variables too, which will
   be properly converted to their values,
   you can even type EOT, as long as it
   is not alone on a line, like this:
EOT;
```

Any ideas as to what is causing the parser to choke?

I'm using PHP 4.4.7.

It is only on one file that this behaviour happens all others follow the PHP defined functionality.

What I am trying to recitify is what could be possibly wrong in the proceding lines so that the PHP parser shows in this failure.

John

changed file contents to :-

```
<?php

$mystring = <<<WHATEVER
   This is some PHP text.
WHATEVER;
?>
```

result =

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file.php on line 5

Any clues

EDIT

original error was to do with `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` this can be caused with jQuery for example "`if(x == y){$('#my_image').hide():}`" is within the heredoc the bigram "{$ will start the parser looking for php variable for substitution.

EDIT

2 good responses.

1) Ch4m3l3on - "`<?php`" vs "`<?`" handling.

2) The Disintegrator - `<q>`had a similar problem with a stupid program that insisted in putting the BOM in a utf-8 file (ignoring preferences)`</q>`.

EDIT

1) Replacing all content with a single  block didn't fix the problem or give any other pointers.

2) No BOM (Byte Order Mark), pity as this or similar majic characters would have explained all symptoms perfectly.

Comment: Time to upgrade to at least 5.1, latest stable is 5.3 :D

Comment: Could you just tell me which line is 737? Is it the

    EOT;

line?

Comment: line 737 is less than the number of lines in the file but not the $mystring= line which is line 1063 - go figure

Comment: Check file's encoding. Some time ago I had a similar problem with a stupid program that insisted in putting the BOM in a utf-8 file (ignoring preferences)

Comment: NOTE: I am not looking for why the heredoc is coded wrongly, because it is coded correctly. This is why I put in the first line $mystring = "<<<WHATEVER"; because that causes no problems, see answer by David Dorward. It is the rest of the file that is causing the parser to choke ONLY when a legal heredoc is found.

Comment: Hi Disintegrator - unfortunatly I cannot up-tick your answer as it is a comment. Please repeat your response as an answer so I can up-tick it. Still don't know the answer but will investigate you're idea.

Comment: Agreed with @Michael -- you definitely need to upgrade; PHP4 is no longer supported, and hasn't been for a while and likely has unpatched security issues, so even if this isn't causing your current problem you should upgrade.

Comment: Can you upload your file somewhere? Because this is either about other parts of the file or your PHP version or something.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. http://eval.in/11513

Comment: php4 had some bugs with parsing the indentation. try the heredoc end to be either on the first char of the line, and at the same identation level as the var assignment. and use the same line break all along the file.

Answer (score 13):

you have to place your ending heredoc at the *beginning* of line. if you use some IDE that have indentation, remove them! your ending heredoc must be vertically in the same line as your ending php tag(

Comment: Best explanation out of many I've read. It has to be left-most aligned.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that there is nothing after the 'WHATEVER;'. Even a space will give a parse error. 
I would delete the line and retype it, hitting `<enter>` immediately after typing the semi-colon.

Comment: Irrelevant, heredoc works ok in pasted into other php files, the Question is why is the parser choking on valid heredoc where it correctly parses string assignment.

Comment: Clearly the problem is not with the heredoc declaration. The problem must somewhere else in the script. Like Pedro Cunha said, check for improperly closed curly brackets. Also you might wanna replace any php short tags with the full ones.

Comment: Hi Ch4m3l3on - unfortunatly I cannot up-tick your answer as it is a comment. Please repeat your response as an answer "<?php" vs "<?" so I can up-tick it. Still don't know the answer but will investigate you're idea.

Comment: You can up-vote comments too ;)

Answer (score 5):

make sure that EOT; is really at the begin of the line.

```
if ($muh="kuh") {
     $foo = <<<EOT
           some text text text
EOT;
}
```

Comment: checked EOT at line start before posting as well as if a space is ok so <<< EOT tested 
as well as <<<EOT plus no lines between EOT..EOT
only letters between EOT..EOT
result send question to stackoverflow to find out if someone knows what could cause symptoms
ie <? handling
} handling
<xxx>..</xxx> handling

Answer (score 2):

What if you try:

```
$mystring = <<<'EOT'
...
EOT;
```

(Notice the single quotes around the first `EOT`)

Answer (score 0):

I just copy/pasted that into a file and it ran without errors. (PHP 5.2.8 (cli) (built: Feb  6 2009 12:33:08))

So the problem is likely something near that code, but not something you included in the question.

Either that, or a change in PHP since your version was built.

Comment: agreed It is only on one file that this behaviour happens all others follow the PHP defined functionality. what is the choke reason though, no one yet has given me any clues

Comment: Since the code provided runs without errors, the choke reason has something to do with the code you haven't shown us — and we don't own crystal balls.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check if you have any unclosed curly bracket (or brace, can't remember).

For example:

```
<?php

while(true) {
    echo "Something\n";

?>
```

Will produce that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep for an uptic, but Ch4m3l3on and Pedro Cunhna are right... an incorrect heredoc probably won't cause that unexpected $end error, but an unclosed curly brace definitely would.